# chain static methods in mongoose doesn't work

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I tried static methods in es6, any clue why I can't chain my static method like below? Is it even possible to chain 2 static methods?

```
//nameModel.js
const schema = new mongoose.Schema({ name: String })
class NameClass {
  static async findAll() {
    return this.find({})
  }
}
schema.loadClass(NameClass)
export const model = initModel('NameSchema', schema)

//controller.js
import { model as NameModel } from '../models/nameModel'
export default () => async (req, res) {
  try {


const test = await NameModel.findAll()
    console.log('test', test) //have all the records

    const response = await NameModel.findAll().sort('-name') // NameMode.sort is not a function
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e)
  }
}
```

What is the diffrence between static and non static method in mongoose schema? I'm confused as the doc only show code sample. I felt it's redundant as it doesn't show difference between two http://mongoosejs.com/docs/advanced_schemas.html

Answer (score 1):

`this` in static method is refer to class function itself, since it defined as a method of a class.

```
class NameClass {
  static async findAll() {
    return this.find({})
  }
}
```

is equal to:

```
class NameClass {}
NameClass.findAll = async function() {
  return this.find({})
}
```

see [MDN Classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes)

Comment: so I should return the NameModel,find({}) instead of this.find({}) in order to do 'chaining'?

Comment: Noop, because async function returns a promise, so `NameModel.findAll()` returns a native promise instance.Try  `const query = await NameModel.findAll(); const response = query.sort('-name')`.

Comment: `query` is already the response object, it doesn't have method of `sort`.

Comment: @Melissa92 You are right, I'm not that familiar with Mongoose, but after reading some docs, maybe we can change the return value of `findAll` static method. `static async findAll() { return () => this.find({}) }`, and then `const query = await NameModel.findAll(); const response = query().sort('-name')`. Hope it can helps.

Comment: oh ok return entire function, will try later.